# php mail function only working on local server and not on remote server

Tags: remote-server, php, localserver

just as the title I created a simple form in HTML

you can see it at http://thee-l.comuv.com/send.php this sends an email to me  with the subject and body text specified I run this on localhost from Apache and I get in my inbox in less than a minute but I then upload it to the remote server the site and it does not email me at all

I have a gmail address so to make it easy I made an outgoing smtp server with smtp2go this was my first php-sent email, I was really happy and right away put it on the remote server and here we are

I am using 000webhost

here is my code

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']){
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp2go.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", 2525);
$to = "lsworkemail112@gmail.com";
$subj = $_POST['topic'];
$body = $_POST['message'];
$header = "From: lsworkemail112@gmail.com";
if (mail($to, $subj, $body, $header))
{
echo "Message sent successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Message sent unsuccessfully";
}
}
else
{
echo "<html>
<form method=\"post\" action=\"send.php\">
Topic: <br/><input type=\"text\" name=\"topic\"/><br/>
Message: <br/><textarea name=\"message\"></textarea><br/>
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\" name=\"submit\"/>
</form>
</html>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code? There are a multitude of reasons this may be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I tried clicking on your link, but apparently your website is under review (possibly for mailing too much/suspected of spamming because of your testing?). Even then, linking to a `.php` page won't show us the code, since the server will execute it and send just the result to the browser. It's better if you copy/paste your code into the question.

Also, as @Computerish said, you may have just run into a limit on your host. How many times have you run your `mail()` code today?

Comment: I emailed myself 4 times then tried on the server the smtp2go lets me do 10 a day

Comment: @Luck: Could you copy the code into your question? There could be an issue with the code looping or something causing you to exceed limits, or possibly some other problem. It's hard to figure it out without seeing exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web hosting company's policies about outgoing mail. There may be a daily limit, a outright ban on it, or it may be an extra service you have to ask for. Almost all hosting companies do something to limit the use of the send() function to prevent spammers from taking advantage of their servers.

Comment: First thing I thought of too. I checked, though, and 000webhost explicitly mentions allowing `mail()`. You're right that he may have hit a limit while testing, but he's making it sound like it never worked on his web host.

Comment: I remember when I was testing a mail() function for something I accidentally wrote an infinite loop into the script. Good thing I was sending emails to myself. I got about 500 emails in about a minute before the script stopped working for the rest of the month.