# Emails are sent on local host but not on Live server

Tags: php, html-email

Im having a form on my website and  emails are sent when on local host but when on a live server the mails does not go through and i get an error message: "Internal Server Error". im wondering whether its an issue with code of the host. kindly help to fix this, thanks in advance

Below is the code

```
<?php

$webmaster_email = "yawsamuel@ghanaeuropeanyouthcongress.com";

$feedback_page = "feedback.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;


function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

elseif (empty($name) || empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}


elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

else {
$to = $webmaster_email; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message: \n $comments"; 

    $headers = "From: $webmaster_email\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );`
}
?>
```

Comment: It must be a firewall issue.

Comment: How is your local set up? Is your live server configured exactly the same way (I believe you have to configure it to actually allow emailing)

Comment: You need to check your error logs. It's most likely you don't have a local mail server configured. Also search before posting, there are many duplicates of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mail function only working on local server and not on remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425557/php-mail-function-only-working-on-local-server-and-not-on-remote-server)

Comment: I just wondering how it is possible to send email on localhost using php function "mail()". Try to use SMTP so it will work on localhost as well as on live server.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, thus resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); // missed out a semi-colon
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" ); // extra backpack
```

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```